# Debian 9 and predictable network interface names

Tags: debian

While playing with my new Debian 9 on Hetzner cloud I've noticed one strange thing. When VM is booted I can see, that eth0 interface is renamed to ens3 (I suspect predictable network names mechanism comes into play). But right after rename is done I can see that ens3 interface name is renamed back to eth0. I see these renames in dmesg output.

```
[    1.471140] virtio_net virtio0 ens3: renamed from eth0
[    3.212154] virtio_net virtio0 eth0: renamed from ens3
```

Can someone help me to find out where is this second interface rename is configured as I'm not able to find such configuration nowhere:( Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the udev rules?

Comment: Yes, I've checked the rules. I looked at /etc/udev/rules.d folder and it is completely empty:/ So because of that I'm saying that I'm not able to find where the second renaming is configured:(

Comment: telcoM either doesn't believe you or hasn't read your comment.  Still, best to check his last suggestion, about "nameif".  Let us know how it goes.

Comment: cat: /etc/mactab: No such file or directory :) So I think that suggestion about "nameif -s" thing is wrong. But I'm starting to think that second renaming is done by the cloud-init. I've tried to disable cloud-init by creating sloud-init.disabled file in /etc/cloud directory and after I rebooted my VM I can see only one renaming to ens3. So as for now I need a way and help to find out how interface renaming is done by cloud-init.

Comment: In the cloud all these things become much clearer. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If Debian 9 was installed from scratch, it uses the new "predictable network interface names" mechanism. If it was upgraded from an earlier version, it still uses old-style naming - and the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` should be present.

The timing information in your log entries indicates there is about 1.7 seconds time between the two rename operations. That would suggest there might be two mechanisms in play: the first line might be `systemd-networkd` within initramfs setting up the new-style names, then the second could be when the root filesystem has been mounted and the "real" udev (as opposed to the mini-udev within initramfs) starts up.

Or, if the admins of the Hetzner cloud have implemented the legacy-style names using a different tool, it might be e.g. `/etc/rc.local` running something like `nameif -s`, which would read `/etc/mactab` and set the interface names according to it.

Or if the Hetzner cloud is using `cloud-init` as you commented, then you might want to check if the `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/custom-networking.cfg` file is present. For more details, see:

http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/network-config-format-v1.html

http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/network-config-format-v2.html

`cloud-init` can have many possible sources of network configuration information, see:

http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/network-config.html#network-configuration-sources

Comment: Debian was not upgraded and it is brand new installation. As I said, rules directory is completely empty. There is no `/etc/mactab` file on my VM. There is no `/etc/rc.local` file on my system. I'm starting to think that second renaming is done by the cloud-init. I've tried to disable cloud-init by creating sloud-init.disabled file in /etc/cloud directory and after I rebooted my VM I can see only one renaming to ens3. So as for now I need a way and help to find out how interface renaming is done by cloud-init.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: I'm not able to see such a file - `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/custom-networking.cfg`on my system. But looking at the cloud-init logs I can see that cloud-init is trying to rename my network interface `util.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['ip', 'link', 'set', 'ens3', 'name', 'eth0'] with allowed return codes [0]` So, I think that I'll uninstall all of this cloud-init nonsense or will leave cloud-init disabled :)

Comment: Cloud-init *may* be doing other things too, that might be important for your ability to use the cloud VM. Like setting up SSH keys to allow you to access your cloud instance. But if you are sure (or willing to experiment), go ahead...

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem with a fresh Debian 10 VM at OVH. Here's what I had to do (apart from modifying `/etc/network/interfaces`):

- remove `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`
- add a file `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg` with the content `network: {config: disabled}` (this was taken from `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/README`